# Cannot restarting in TCP mode port: 5555

Tags: android, tcp

I try to use ADB of android studio via wifi by some tutorial in web like a:
connect phone to lap via usb, go to cmd and type: `adb tcpip 5555`
and then output of cmd will "restarting in TCP mode port: 5555"

But when i type `adb tcpip 5555` and enter. It alway hang on, i waited it a long time but no thing happen

[image]

I checked the device connect and see

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, just unplug your USB cord and it'll connect right after by itself

In another hand, I advice you to:

**unplug usb** and kill the server

```
adb kill-server
```

**plug usb** [wait 5sec] and get the IP adress of your device

```
adb shell netcfg
```

Type

```
adb tcpip 5555 //or any port you want
```

[wait 5sec] and **unplug usb**

Now you connect

```
adb connect <device ip>:5555
```

Bamm !

Answer (score 0):

Just close Android Studio.

If you are getting "off-line" device, just disconnect your phone and restart it and try again, of course, Android Studio should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps worked for me:

Unplug your device, then try to restart your PC and android device, then try to connect your device and execute adb commands.